# Retrieve array value from PHP

Tags: php, geoip

I have this function:

```
print_r(geoip_record_by_name('php.net'));
```

This results in:

```
Array ( 
   [continent_code] => NA 
   [country_code] => US
   [country_code3] => USA 
   [country_name] => United States 
   [region] => CA [city] => Sunnyvale 
   [postal_code] => 94089 
   [latitude] => 37.424900054932 
   [longitude] => -122.0074005127 
   [dma_code] => 807
   [area_code] => 408 
)
```

I want to retrieve the region value, but

```
geoip_record_by_name('php.net')['region'];
```

gives a blank result.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: He didn't say it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

The following syntax is only supported in **PHP >= 5.4**:

```
geoip_record_by_name('php.net')['region'];
```

If you are using some other version, you will have to do:

```
$arr = geoip_record_by_name('php.net');
echo $arr['region'];
```

**Docs:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Comment: @Rocket: Yep and a lot more, I love JS-like new array syntax too `$arr = [.....];`

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in PHP (< 5.4).  You need to save the array as a variable first.

```
$geoip = geoip_record_by_name('php.net');
echo $geoip['region'];
```

Array docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayName = geoip_record_by_name('php.net');
echo $arrayName['region'];
```

You can only used the syntax you used in PHP 5.4